# How to generate a magic number and populate it to the database upon user registration?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am in search of a way to assign a random generated number-letter combination to a user upon registering on my page.

So if a user registers on my site, there shall be a random generated number-letter combination (let's call it `magic number`) assigned to this user and populated to the PostgreSQL users table.

Is there a common approach to do so?

Would I have to define such function within the existing class or is there a different workflow?

This is my `model` (inherited from Djangos `AbstractUser` model):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    pass
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Comment: This is sometimes done with a `uuid`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Comment: ah nice thanks! So to get it right, this replaces the primary-key?

Comment: you *can* replace it with the primary key, although that is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a common approach to do so?

It looks like what you want is something (related) to a [*Universally Unique Identifier (UUID)* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID), it is a 128-bit number, that is often represented by a hexadecimal notation. This is often used if two (or more servers) need to assign ids that should be unique, but they do not have knowledge of the ids that the other server has already assigned. Strictly speaking it is possible that two servers generate the same UUID. But it would take generating approximately 2.71×10<sup>18</sup> numbers to have a 50% chance that there are two UUIDs that are the same, which looks reasonably large to assume it will not happen.

Recent versions of Django have a [**`UUIDField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield) which helps you tho work with UUIDs. As is documented, you thus can use this with:

> ```
> import uuid
> from django.db import models
>
> class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
>     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
> ```

Note that you do not per se need to make this the primary key. You can also use this as an extra unique value that is used together with the primary key (like for example a slug is somtimes used for that purpose as well):

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class MyUUIDModel(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

If you for example want to work with a [**`GenericForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey), then you might want to use the original primary key. Since otherwise referencing to both models that use a `UUIDField` and an `AutoField` might get cumbersome.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive reply. I will use the suggested solution for my project which seems to fit nicely!